# Python - using AND in an IF to reference 2 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pyproj

I am trying to write a python function using the module pyproj which will do coordinate conversion based on two factors - the ending of the file name and the name of 2 rows.

For example: `if self.file_crs == 'IG'` which is if the file ending is IG for Irish Grid

AND

```
for idx,el in enumerate(row):
  if keys[idx].capitalize() in ['Easting', 'Northing']:
```

which is if the two columns are called Easting and Northing

THEN RUN

```
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:29903') # Irish Grid
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS84
x1, y1 = row[1], row[2]  # easting, northing
x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
row[1], row[2] = y2, x2
```

How can I combine these to look something like:

```
if self.file_crs == 'IG' and keys[idx].capitalize() in ['Easting', 'Northing']:
  inProj = Proj(init='epsg:29903') # Irish Grid
  outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS84
  x1, y1 = row[1], row[2]  # easting, northing
  x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
  row[1], row[2] = y2, x2
```

I need to be able to reference idx beforehand so it is recognised in my 'if' statement

**EDIT**

keys are the row names in the csv which is being parsed.

```
if line_count == 0:
                    keys = row
```

The rows are as follows

| Name | Easting | Northing | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test1 | 169973 | 77712 | 01/01/2020 09:51:03 AM |

Comment: What are `keys` and `row`?

Comment: @quamrana sorry, see edited question!

Comment: Do you mean that the `keys` are the column names and `row` is one row at a time? Can you give an example of one row?

Comment: @quamrana exactly! And yes I have included an example of a row

Comment: First I would say that you should check the column names when `line_count == 0` and throw an exception if they are not what you expect. That would eliminate one of the complexities.

Comment: yes I have done that  with ```line_count += 1``` thank you!

Comment: `keys[idx].lower()` will never be in `['Easting', 'Northing']`, E/N are up-case ! You only need to iterate iterate on rows.

Comment: apologies, they are changed to capitalize now. But I still need a way to run ```if self.file_crs == 'IG' and keys[idx].capitalize() in ['Easting', 'Northing']:```

Comment: Do you get any errors with: `keys[idx].capitalize()`?

Comment: @quamrana nope, it works fine! My issue is just trying to combine the 2 IF statements into 1. Then I get that error ```invalid syntax```

Comment: Can you update your question to show all the parts in sequence? Its very difficult to see which bit follows which. I think you only need to check the keys at the time you are reading the first line.

Comment: @quamrana that should be it now. It is at the ```# Changing of CRS based on file name``` part that I wish to include the new ```if self.file_crs == 'IG' and keys[idx].capitalize() in ['Easting', 'Northing']:```

Comment: Ok, I see what is going on now. I'll have a look to see if we can get what you need.

Comment: Do you need the: `inProj` and `outProj` variables to be a new instance for each row?

Comment: @quamrana I do yes!

Comment: Oh, I was hoping that they could be instantiated once and reused for each row.

Comment: So, does your `transform()` function modify the `inProj` and `outProj` variables?

Comment: @quamrana hmm well I hadn't thought of that, but if you feel it would work well I am willing to give it a try! The ```transform()``` takes the CRS identified in the ```inProj``` and ```outProj``` and uses them to correctly convert the coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I tried this in a make-shift test harness and this runs:

```py
class TestPositions:
    def __init__(self, crs):
        self.file_crs = crs

    def process_incoming_file(self, bucket, key, event):
        if self.file_crs == 'BNG':
            inProj = Proj(init="epsg:27700")  # British National Grid
            outProj = Proj(init="epsg:4326")  # WGS84
        else:
            inProj = Proj(init='epsg:29903')  # Irish Grid
            outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')  # WGS84

        try:

            decoded_content = ['Name|Easting|Northing|Time', 'Test1|169973|77712|01/01/2020 09:51:03 AM']
            print('processing data')
            rows = csv.reader(decoded_content, delimiter='|')
            for line_count, row in enumerate(rows):
                if line_count == 0:
                    keys = [title.lower() for title in row]
                    print('keys', keys)
                    isEasting = ('easting' in keys)
                else:
                    json_doc = {}
                    for idx, el in enumerate(row):
                        if keys[idx] in ['time', 'date serviced', 'timestamp']:
                            timestamp = self.format_timestring(el)
                        else:
                            json_doc[keys[idx]] = el

                    if isEasting:
                        json_doc['easting'], json_doc['northing'] = transform(inProj, outProj, json_doc['easting'], json_doc['northing'])
                        json_doc['latitude'] = json_doc.pop('easting')
                        json_doc['longitude'] = json_doc.pop('northing')
                    geom = Point(json_doc['Longitude'], json_doc['Latitude'])
                    WKB_format = wkb.dumps(geom, hex=True, srid=4326)

                    fid = uuid.uuid4()  # assign new UUID to each row

                    print(json_doc['name'])
                    print(fid)
                    print(timestamp)
                    print(WKB_format)
                    print(json_doc)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception: {e.__class__.__name__}({e})')
```

You can see how I generate `inProj` and `outProj` at the beginning of the method so it is done once per call to `process_incoming_file()`.

I have hardcoded `decoded_content`. You will need your original:

```py
            response = self.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            decoded_content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
            print(decoded_content)

            rows = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
            # no need to convert to a list
```

You will notice that I check the column names at the first line and throw an exception as it will be pointless to carry on with missing information.

Also, once I copy the cells into `json_doc`, there is no need to refer to `row` again in the loop.

**Update:**

I added a check for `'easting'` as a proxy for which set of column names would be present. So, `if isEasting:` make the conversion happen, else it is assumed that no conversion is necessary.

Comment: I seem to be getting the error ```invalid syntax (<fstring>, line 1)``` if I try this method. I am using python 3.6 for reference

Comment: Ok, try this line: `raise RuntimeError(f'keys={keys} not valid')`

Comment: yes that works thanks! Just one more question -  see the following lines ```if ('easting' not in keys) or ('northing' not in keys):
                        raise RuntimeError(f'{keys=} not valid')``` The column headings can be easting and northing or longitude and latitude - I need it the function to recognise if its ```easting``` and ```northing``` then carry out ```inProj``` and ```outProj```, otherwise, if it is ```longitude``` and ```latitude``` leave as is.

Comment: Ok, so will the input be invalid if its the case that the headings are neither pair, or is it *so* likely that it *will* be one or the other it isn't worth checking?

Comment: The headings will always be either ```easting``` and ```northing``` or ```longitude``` and ```latitude```. Coordinate conversion is only required to take place if the headings are in ```easting and northing``` format

Comment: Ok, see my update. I've assumed that exactly one or the other will be present.

Comment: Okay yes I think this will work. I just need to figure out where to add ```line_count += 1```, as at present the eastings/northings can't be converted as it only recognises the string and not the numbers below.

Comment: I have `line_count` incorporated in the for loop by using `enumerate()`. It gets incremented automatically.

Comment: yes but I get the error ```Exception: TypeError(must be real number, not str)``` when the ```inProj and outProj``` are ran due to it picking up on the column names rather than the values underneath

Comment: Perhaps you should paste your current code as an answer so I can see what you're doing. With my code, there is no way that `transform()` can get column names instead of lat/lon numbers.

Comment: ok, I have done so! Apologies for all the confusion and your help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In reply to above answer

```
    def process_incoming_file(self, bucket, key, event):
        if self.file_crs == 'BNG':
            inProj = Proj(init="epsg:27700")  # British National Grid
            outProj = Proj(init="epsg:4326")  # WGS84
        else:
            inProj = Proj(init='epsg:29903')  # Irish Grid
            outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')  # WGS84

        try:
            response = self.client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
            decoded_content = response['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
            print(decoded_content)
            print('processing data')
            rows = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
            for line_count, row in enumerate(rows):
                if line_count == 0:
                    keys = [title.lower() for title in row]
                    print('keys', keys)
                    isEasting = ('easting' in keys)
                else:
                    json_doc = {}
                    for idx, el in enumerate(row):
                        if keys[idx] in ['time', 'date serviced', 'timestamp']:
                            timestamp = self.format_timestring(el)
                        else:
                            json_doc[keys[idx]] = el

                    if isEasting:
                        json_doc['easting'], json_doc['northing'] = transform(inProj, outProj, json_doc['easting'], json_doc['northing'])
                        json_doc['latitude'] = json_doc.pop('easting')
                        json_doc['longitude'] = json_doc.pop('northing')
                    geom = Point(json_doc['longitude'], json_doc['latitude'])
                    WKB_format = wkb.dumps(geom, hex=True, srid=4326)

                    fid = uuid.uuid4()  # assign new UUID to each row

                    print(json_doc['name'])
                    print(fid)
                    print(timestamp)
                    print(WKB_format)
                    print(json_doc)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Exception: {e.__class__.__name__}({e})')
```

Comment: You may need to temporarily remove the `try:except:` in order to get an Error Traceback to be able to tell exactly where the error about numbers not strings comes from.

Comment: I've gone through the code and it is ```geom = Point(json_doc['longitude'], json_doc['latitude'])
                    WKB_format = wkb.dumps(geom, hex=True, srid=4326)``` which throws it off with the error ```TypeError(must be real number, not str)```. This happened me in my original code until I added ```line_count += 1```

Comment: What happens if you have either: `geom = Point(int(json_doc['longitude']), int(json_doc['latitude']))` or `geom = Point(float(json_doc['longitude']), float(json_doc['latitude']))`?

Comment: The first gives me this error ```ValueError(invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-8.6077881')```

Comment: the second works perfectly!!!! Finally - thank you!!!!